# HP SmartArray Rebuild Logical Drive without data loss

Tags: hp, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, data-recovery

First, let me explain our situation:

We had an HP server with a RAID 1 over 2 drives (for the OS) and a RAID 5 over 4 drives (for VM data). The raid recently failed. I say the word failed very loosely because to this day I still don't know what exactly caused it. We thought at first a failed drive was the problem. But, after running the HP Offline ACU the status of the drive originally thought to be failed is indeed showing no errors. However, we have another drive (which originally didn't show any errors) now showing a warning that it might fail soon.

Now, here is my question:

Can we see how the raid was configured before and configure it exactly as is and not lose any data? Or are we going to lose data no matter what? The backups we have are not completely up-to-date so I want to try to restore data back to how it was at all costs. I am just not sure if when I recreate the logical volume (exactly how it was) if my data will still be purged?

Is there a command line utility in ACU Offline that will allow me to recreate a logical volume that will NOT purge data if the GUI will?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can you provide the model number and generation of your HP server?

Comment: HP ProLiant DL380 G6

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're in a confusing situation. It's hard to follow what you want and what the expected outcome is.

For your server, though...

- An HP DL380 G6 has an onboard RAID controller. It's the HP Smart Array P410 controller.
- If you have errors of any sort, you should provide them in your question. Please examine your ILO's IML log or look at the POST messages on the screen of the server.
- These RAID controllers rarely fail. If they do, it's a motherboard replacement. So keep that in mind.
- HP RAID configurations are stored on disk, not the controller. So you can move these drives to another server if the array is healthy.

Comment: Thanks. I have just read the ACU error code. It says error 720. Here's the details on that:

SMART Array P410i in embedded slot has an unsupported configuration. You may reconfigure the controller but the existing configuration may be overwritten and potentially lost.

Comment: Your cache unit may be bad. Do you have a raid battery?